# Construct reflection of a point on a line with respect to a parallel line knowing a point and its reflection

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Below are two lines $(D)$ and $(\Delta)$.
We are given a point $M$ on $(D)$ and its reflection wtr $(\Delta)$.
If $A$ is another point on $(D)$, it is asked to construct the reflection of it wtr $(\Delta)$ Using straightedge only.

I tried to use $J = (AN)\cap (\Delta)$ but in vain

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Ruler & Compass constructions we can draw a parallel to a given straight line through another point not on it using a compass. If this is allowed,

[image]

draw a line parallel to MN through A (red), another  line parallel to MA through N (blue) intersecting at P, the required image of A.

If Compass not allowed, can a Set square used by engineers/draftsmen be allowed ? If so, another known procedure to draw parallels:

One edge of a set square  is aligned to the given line, another edge is made to slide on another edge till it goes through the given point, to draw parallel lines...in both cases.

Comment: Thanks but compass is not allowed